# Sweetalert2 only works with first button in foreach

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

The following code shows a popup delete confirmation for different files in a gallery and on confirm it loads `delete.php` file to initiate deletion.
Everything works, but only the first button in a gallery loads the popup.
I want to use  `id="custom-sa-warning<?php echo $i++; ?>` ,it creates  `id="custom-sa-warning0` ,  `id="custom-sa-warning1` and so on. But I dont know how to make it work with the javascript function.

html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="custom-sa-warning" data-fileId="<?php echo $differentfileids; ?>">Click me</button>
```

js:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("custom-sa-warning") && document.getElementById("custom-sa-warning").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var el = event.target || event.srcElement;
    var fileId = el.getAttribute('data-fileId');
    Swal.fire({
        html: '<div class="mt-3"><lord-icon src="https://cdn.lordicon.com/gsqxdxog.json" trigger="loop" colors="primary:#f7b84b,secondary:#f06548" style="width:100px;height:100px"></lord-icon><div class="mt-4 pt-2 fs-15 mx-5"><h4>Are you Sure ?</h4><p class="text-muted mx-4 mb-0">Are you Sure You want to Delete this Account ?</p></div></div>',
        showCancelButton: !0,
        confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-primary w-xs me-2 mb-1",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, Delete It!",
        cancelButtonClass: "btn btn-danger w-xs mb-1",
        buttonsStyling: !1,
        showCloseButton: !0
    }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
     window.location.href = "https://somedimain.com/delete.php?id=" + fileId
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Rather than giving your elements incremental ids, give them a single `class`, and then use `querySelectorAll('.yourClass').forEach(el => {...})` to add your click event handler to each. Or you can look into using ["event delegation"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) as another alternative.

Comment: @NickParsons, if possible please give a working example, I am new to coding javascript.

Comment: Please see the linked questions above your question for some examples.